# Eliminating IF statement using bitwise operators

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bit, bitwise-operators

I am trying to eliminate an IF statement whereby if I receive the number 32 I would like a '1', but any other number I would like a '0'.

32 is 0010 0000 so I thought about XOR-ing my input number with 1101 1111. Therefore if I get the number 32 I end up with 1111 1111.

Now is there any way of AND-ing the individual bits (1111 1111), because if one of my XOR results is a 0, it means my final AND-ed value is 0, otherwise its a 1?

EDIT: Using GCC, not Intel compiler (because I know there are a lot of intrinsic functions there)

Comment: what do you mean that its still a conditional? that's not a conditional? there would be no branch instructions generated? (so i think what you just said would be great!?)

Comment: == is a condition. Even if you explicitly have an `if` statement, the compiler could optimize it away, the only way to tell is to look at the generated assembly.

Comment: Perhaps.. (x & 32) >> (5 + (x & ~32)). First part only leaves 1 bit when x = 32, and second part shifts it out if any other bit is 1. Quite baroque :P

Comment: @epx: `(x & 32) && !(x & ~32)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expression

```
  !(x ^ 32)
```

will do the trick for you if you insist.

That will always work in C, and will also work in almost all C++ settings. Technically in C++ it evaluates to a boolean which in almost all circumstances will work like 0 or 1, but if you want a technically correct C++ answer:

```
  (0 | !(x^32))
```

or:

```
(int)!(x ^ 32)
```

or with the more modern / verbose C++ casting

```
static_cast<int>(x ^ 32)
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed to be 1 if true? Normally it is, but I don't think it is guaranteed.

Comment: @epx, Yes, `true` is guaranteed to be 1 per [conv.prom].

Comment: How does this actually work? I dont see how negating the XOR would work? Say the result of my XOR was 1111 0011, why does "!(1111 0011)" = 0?

Comment: The only way of producing 0 bits as a result of XOR is if the two input bits are the same. Therefore the only way of producing an all zero bit answer is if the two input integers are the same. Therefore `x^32` will be zero if an only if `x=32`. Therefore `!(x^32)` will be 1 if and only if `x=32`, else it will be zero. 1 is guaranteed to be equal to true and 0 false in response to the other commenter.

Comment: `!z` = 0 unless `z = 0` in which case `!z = 1`.

Comment: The expression is the somewhat obfuscated equivalent of `!(x ^ 32 == 0)`.  In this case, probably valid, since the question seems to be asking about a means of obfuscating anyway.

Comment: `!z` is _never_ equal to `0` or or to `1`.  It's either `true` or `false`.

Comment: `!z` *is* equal to `0` or `1` in C (the question is tagged both C and C++). But in any case even in C++ evaluation or `0` or `1` as a boolean works as `false`/`true` respectively.

Comment: Argh! C as well.  In C++, for reasons of C compatibility, all numeric types and all pointer types will convert implicitly to a `bool`, although good programmers avoid this.  You're talking about going the other way, however: a `bool` will convert to another numeric type, with the values of `0` or `1`, in most (but not all) contexts.  But the expression itself doesn't have the value `0` or `1`.  (But since the only possible reason for wanting to do this is obfuscation, throwing in a few extra implicit conversions can't hurt.)

Comment: @JamesKanze OK I can imagine a couple of hypothetical situations in C++ where there would be a different answer and have adapted my answer appropriately.

Comment: what is to stop me from doing (x==32)? x==32 gives 1 when they are identical and 0 when they are not?

Comment: @user997112 nothing, save that you said you wanted to use bitwise operators.

Comment: @abligh oh sorry- when I wrote the question I completely forgot the booleans map to 0 and 1. Was thinking in bits!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int fun(int x)
{
   //   32 == 0010 0000
   // 0xDF == 1101 1111
   return (((x ^ 32) & 0xDF) == 0);
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << "fun(32): " << fun(32) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "fun(16): " << fun(16) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "fun(18): " << fun(18) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "fun(48): " << fun(48) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience optimizing actual low level code on real hardware with tools like oprofile, convoluted branchless code like '(x & 32) && !(x & ~32)', '!(x ^ 32)' or '(x & 32) >> (5 + (x & ~32))' compiles to *many* more instructions than 'if (x==32) blah else foo;'

The simple if statement can usually be implemented with a conditional move with no branch misprediction penalty.

Comment: But the only possible purpose of eliminating the `if` is to obfuscate anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you do an exclusive OR (i.e, XOR) with the same number you always get 0. So why don't you XOR with 32 and negate the outcome?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the most obvious would be just `int result = static_cast<int>(x==32)`.

Answer (score 0):

For an integer `x`, if you are guaranteed the only possible values are `0` and `32` and would like to transform these values to `0` and `1` respectively, then this operation will suffice:

```
x >>= 5; // 0x00000000 goes to 0x00000000, 0x00000020 goes to 0x00000001
```

Answer (score 0):

Take x and divide by 32 (shift right 5 bits) and then mask off all the bits other than the first bit:

```
unsigned int r = (x>>5)&1;
```

For *any* number with the 6th bit set (Decimal 32) the first bit (Decimal 1) will now be set. The other bits need to be masked off, otherwise a number like 96 (32 + 64) would produce a result of 3.