# Two different loop or two condition in a loop speed comparison

Tags: c#, performance, loops

I have two loop right now and inside of it there is some assignments, but I have to make it in a fastest way.

```
        for (var i = 0; i < Math.Min(data.elementsOne.Count(), 5)) ; i++) {
            if (data.PairSymbol == "xxx") { oldxxxA = xxxAa; xxxAa = data.elementsOne[0].Amount; oldxxxB = xxxBb; xxxBb = data.elementsTwo[0].Amount; }
            //I HAVE 20 IF BLOCK INSIDE OF IT.  
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < (Math.Min(data.elementsOne.Count(), 5)) || i < Math.Min(data.elementsTwo.Count(), 5); i++)
        {
            if (data.PairSymbol == "xxx") { oldxxxA = xxxAa; xxxAa = data.elementsOne[0].Amount; oldxxxB = xxxBb; xxxBb = data.elementsTwo[0].Amount; }
            //I HAVE 20 IF BLOCK INSIDE OF IT.  
        }
```

When i trying to get better result , i thought i can do it like below one but result look worse.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < (Math.Min(data.elementsOne.Count(), 5)) || i < Math.Min(data.elementsTwo.Count(), 5); i++)
    {
        if (data.PairSymbol == "xxx") { oldxxxA = xxxAa; xxxAa = data.elementsOne[0].Amount; oldxxxB = xxxBb; xxxBb = data.elementsTwo[0].Amount; } 
        //I HAVE 20 IF BLOCK INSIDE OF IT.                          
    }
```

What is wrong ? Any idea how can i speed up? (The most important thing is speed, dont think memory).

ps. I changed code because of some security problems, dont mind syntax errors, and elementsOne.count= elementsTwo.count same almost all time. Dont think there is only 5 items in loop, there is another loop outside, its continuous loop. Sorry for my english

Comment: Putting everything on one line doesnt make it faster. Just saying, however 1 loops is surely better than 2

Comment: @MichaelRandall there was two loop , now one loop.? ie. before 5+5 in two loop, now 5

Comment: So do you have a performance problem ? Also its probably better to cache this result `data.elementsOne[0]` if its always the same

Comment: - since its without a lot of dependency,you could `task.parallel` it to get all out of you cpus
- whats the type of  `data` ? is `Pairsymbol` and `Amount` a property ? if so, post the getters code, maybe theres some speed in that too.  if elementsOne is not an array, the index[0] could also be cached, if its an array its ok.

Comment: What you are doing is equivalent to : Max(A,B) when you really want Min.  So replace the || with &&.

Comment: `i` is unused in your loop, so using 0 loops would be even faster than 1 or 2 loops ;-)

Comment: @MichaelRandall always changing via websocket

Comment: @jdweng im not trying to decrease loop. I got your idea but this different

Comment: @Jarod42 its like i=0; i<5;i++  , to make 5 times for example. So loops are using i

Comment: Suppose you have i < min(2,5)  || i < min(3,5)  The answer is 3, not 2.

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer thanks for task.parallel, i will try to implement my program. elementsOne is an array.

Comment: you have two loop first min(2.5), second min(3.5)... two loops in total 5, but now 3. @jdweng

Comment: @SacmaŞeyler: your loop content has no real side effects: `if (data.PairSymbol == "xxx") {oldxxxA = xxxAa = data.elementsOne[0].Amount; oldxxxB = xxxBb = data.elementsTwo[0].Amount;`} would do the job of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance, you should definitely seek to avoid having `if` statements in your loops. An `if` causes branching which means you are in the hands of the CPU branch predictor.

So yes, you will very *likely* see better performance if you have some 20 loops without an `if` statement that will be true in like 5% of the cases. Try that and see if it helps. Also, make sure to cache the value of `Count()` as that might imply an additional loop.

Comment: I'm using ifs for assignments, how can i make it without if ?

Comment: If you're looking to optimize conditional assignments I would argue that C# is not the right tool in the first place. Anyway, sometimes you can avoid branching with repetitive **integer** operations like `&=` and `|=` etc. You need to find clever operations that can safely be applied without guarding with an `if`. Check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995355/eliminating-if-statement-using-bitwise-operators) and then maybe [this](https://www.infoq.com/articles/making-code-faster-taming-branches/).